# Form Closed Event is not being fired

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, events, taskmanager

When the Application is being closed from **Task Manager** ,than `Form_Closed` **Event** is not firing ,is there a way how to handle this ,because my Application is writing a text file on run-time always ,so i need to finalize data which holds a thread and close the `StreamWriter` on `Form_Closed` ,so how to handle that no matter how my Application is being Closed ,*From User ,ALT+f4 or Task Manager*

Comment: may need to add POWER CUT into your list :)

Comment: Killing a process, in fact DOES really kill the process. No events will fire, no finally block will be run.

Comment: @leppie so that means i can have an exploit in my App which is impossible to close ?

Comment: @Cody: I dont understand what you mean.

Comment: @leppie I meant i have a issue which is impossible to fix ,because i really really need that .Another solution could be by preventing Task Manager to close my App. something like Antiviruses had ,so i could allow application Shut Down only from within the Application .

Comment: This is exactly why you shouldn't write on exit only but after a modification. Write-on-exit is terrible UX. Imagine the PC freezing and requiring a hard restart... everything the user did in your program would be gone.

Comment: Preventing the user from closing your application via the task manager would move it closely to the realm of malware. Also, antivirus software can only do this because the "real thing" runs as a system service (and possibly even a driver). Don't try doing that in a normal program...

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `IDisposable` interface and call `Dispose()` on the `StreamWriter` from there.

Answer (score 0):

To get this case you need to handle the [Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.exit.aspx) event.

> Occurs just before an application shuts down, and cannot be canceled.

Here you can make sure that all data is written to the file and it's closed properly - if it's not already closed of course.

Comment: This wont work also ,try applying this and close the Application from Task Manager it wont rise this event

Comment: @Cody - Oh, I thought it did. Are you killing the process from the "Processes" tab or ending the task from the "Applications" tab?

Comment: yes im killing the process from Processes tab ,and also from external Application to test it with Process.kill();

Comment: @Cody - in that case you'll not get any notification in your application that it's about to close.